# Evaluating mongo DB performance

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a collection in a mongoDB on which I have set user preferences. I  have a very large number of objects in one particular collection, and user can follow a key in the collection. For example:

```
colletionx { key1: value1, key2: value2 : key3: value3 .. keyn:valuen}
```

Now the user can follow any number of keys, i.e., when key1 equals some value update me. (Very much similar similar to the Twitter "follow" feature).

Now how can I efficiently do this?

Also if I query mongo with a query like this:

```
 db.collection.find({ keyId : 290})
```

or  `db.collection.find({ keyId : { $in [ 290] } })` will there be any drastic performance improvement when there are millions of users and all follow 1 show.

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the biggest concerns with having large amounts of data in any database is that when you are querying, you want to avoid hitting the disk.  Mongodb does a fairly good job of keeping data in memory but if your data set outgrows your memory, you will start swapping and that will hurt your performance.

There shouldnt be much of a difference between doing an `$eq` query and an `$in` query as long as there is an index on the key you are querying.  If there is no index, you'll do a full collection scan.

Answer (score 0):

For large amount of data it is very recommended to work with [Sharding](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding)
It will allow you to have the data splitted between shards, thus your index could fit the ram memory. I think findOne by index should be quite  efficient. The only thing that can harm your performance in this case is only massive writes in addition to your reads operations. Since the mongo have a global lock.